# Conditional cell template in ui-grid angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to add conditional when showing data in `ui-grid` cellTemplate below:

```
$scope.status = ['Active', 'Non Active', 'Deleted'];
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'code'
    }, {
        field: 'name'
    }, {
        field: 'status',
        cellTemplate: '<div>{{status[row.entity.status]}}</div>'
    }]
};
```

The expected result should be row status show `Active/NonActive/Deleted`.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdS2C49wHceRdZ3eCcvi?p=preview)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use `externalScopes`.

In your markup define the gridholder like this.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="states" class="grid"></div>
```

And in your controller use this code:

```
var statusTxt = ['Active', 'Non Active', 'Deleted'];

$scope.states = {
  showMe: function(val) {
    return statusTxt[val];
  }
};

var statusTemplate = '<div>{{getExternalScopes().showMe(row.entity.status)}}</div>';
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'code'
  }, {
    field: 'name'
  }, {
    field: 'status',
    cellTemplate: statusTemplate
  }]
};
```

Or use an angular filter.

Note that this only **renders** text. The best approach would be to transform `myData` to have real text states before using it in ui-grid. Just in case you want to do some text based filtering later on.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1VaWYZr1PjIsMRCokJW?p=preview)

Comment: as of now  (3.0.0RC18)  `getExternalScopes()` is not working use `grid.appScope` instead, like this:  `var statusTemplate = '<div>{{grid.appScope.states.showMe(row.entity.status)}}</div>';`

Comment: I am using "ui-grid - v3.0.0-RC.18 - 2014-12-09" and getExternalScopes() is working as expected.

Comment: Keep in mind that those guys are working hard to get this ball rolling. As you can see (in the documentation) the Tutorial for external scopes is gone and was replaced by this one http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope. RC means Release Candidate and is not the finished version.

Comment: Thanks @mainguy for your comment.

Answer (score 19):

I would suggest to use `ng-if` solve this problem.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'code'
    }, {
        field: 'name'
    }, {
        field: 'status',
        cellTemplate: '<div ng-if="row.entity.status == 0">Active</div><div ng-if="row.entity.status == 1">Non Active</div>'
    }]
};
```

Comment: Simplest solution is to use ng-if as given above

Comment: sweet and simple solution !!

Answer (score 15):

I have got another solution for you without using external scopes:

The Template looks like this:

```
var statusTemplate = '<div>{{COL_FIELD == 0 ? "Active" : (COL_FIELD == 1 ? "Non Active" : "Deleted")}}</div>';
```

Here is the plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OZtU7GrOskdqwHW5FIVz?p=preview

Comment: Yep, that's cool! Although I still think preparing the data is the best way. With many states this could turn into a lengthy template. Nonetheless: +1

Comment: Yep, you are so right. And I was wondering what to do, if this gets more complex. So I'm glad that i found your answer above!

Comment: This works. Also it answers my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070340/set-cell-value-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 10):

Use a `cellFilter`.

```
columnDefs: [{
    field: 'code'
}, {
    field: 'name'
}, {
    field: 'status',
    cellFilter: 'mapStatus'
}]


app.filter('mapStatus', function() {

    var statusMap = ['Active', 'Non Active', 'Deleted'];

    return function(code) {
        if (!angular.isDefined(code) || code < 0 || code > 2) {
            return '';
        } else {
            return statusMap[code];
        }
    };
});
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JwCrrrP4fJz85O0C0oEE?p=preview)

Comment: Cool stuff! I will definitely use this, if i don't have to change style depending on the value.

Answer (score 3):

You must change your template. When you are referring to external scopes in angular-ui-grid you may use grid.appScope.

```
var statusTemplate = '<div>{{grid.appScope.status[row.entity.status]}}</div>';
```

Comment: I meant var statusTemplate = '<div>{{grid.appScope.status[row.entity.status]}}</div>';

Answer (score 0):

Try below script. It is working for me.

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

  var statusTxt = ['Active', 'Non Active', 'Deleted'];

$scope.showMe= function(val) {
    return statusTxt[val];
  };

var statusTemplate = '<div>{{grid.appScope.showMe(row.entity.status)}}</div>';
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [{
    field: 'code'
  }, {
    field: 'name'
  }, {
    field: 'status',
    cellTemplate: statusTemplate
  }]
};

$scope.gridOptions.data = [{
  "code": "Cox",
  "name": "Carney",
  "status": 0
}, {
  "code": "Lorraine",
  "name": "Wise",
  "status": 1
}, {
  "code": "Nancy",
  "name": "Waters",
  "status": 2
  }];
  }
]);
```