# Angular UI Grid, adding a button to a row cell via templating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I got the following `gridOptions.columnDefs`

```
 $scope.generateReport = function(row) {
     alert("Test");
 };

 $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
     { name: 'Action', 
       cellEditableCondition: false, 
       cellTemplate: '<button ng-click="grid.appScope.generateReport(row)"> 
                       Report 
                      </button>' 
     }];
```

It's not working, the button shows but once clicked its not calling the function. I'm following their guide [Here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope), and I'm using `ui-grid - v3.0.0-RC.18`.

I got the following for my html.

```
        <div id="grid1"
             ui-grid="gridOptions"
             ui-grid-cellnav
             ui-grid-edit
             ui-grid-expandable
             ui-grid-exporter
             class="myGrid">
        </div>
```

I also tried to add an `external-scope` but didn't make a difference..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My ng-click for a button in a ui-grid row looks like this.

```
ng-click="getExternalScopes().delete($event, row)
```

My controller has $scope injected and the first line creates the reference (I believe) to the external scope.

```
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
$scope.$scope = $scope;
```

The HTML looks like this, which refers to the external scope.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="someClass" external-scopes="$scope" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns></div>
```

Here is my entire cellTemplate if it helps...

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope"><button class="btn btn-danger {{getExternalScopes().deleteButtonClass(row)}} btn-xs btn-block" ng-click="getExternalScopes().delete($event, row)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></div>
```

Comment: Just read on another post that external-scope is being slowly deprecated. It works in the version I am using now though, which is a month or two old.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688746/conditional-cell-template-in-ui-grid-angularjs?rq=1

Comment: I upgraded to their latest release RC20 and its working fine with `grid.appScope.generateReport`. I had R18 and supposedly it should've worked with that release as well too. What version are you using in your example?

Comment: I am using v3.0.0-RC.18. I upgraded recently to the latest release, but the tabbing behaviour of editable grids had changed drastically, so I went back to the old release for now. Looks like you perhaps had a mismatch between documentation and code?

Comment: Yeah pretty much so, thanks for your answer though it does work on RC18 so I will accept  and hopefully others that get stuck here can see this.