# binding html in angularjs grid cell template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I have read this question before [Conditional cell template in ui-grid angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688746/conditional-cell-template-in-ui-grid-angularjs) and its absolutely worked for me, but I am just wondering how to display html like a button tag instead of text, because when I am trying to change it to html, it always display html as text

Thanks and sorry because of my bad english

js file

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
        field: 'action',
        displayName: label.action,
        width : 175,
        enableCellEdit: false,
        cellTemplate: '<div>{{grid.appScope.states.showMe(row.entity.j_code, row.entity.branch_cd)}}</div>',            
    }];

scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = comlumnDefs;
$scope.states = {
    showMe: function(j_code, branch_cd) {
        template = "<button class='btn-small btn-green btn-add'>Add</button>";
        if (j_code != "" && branch_cd != "") {
            template += "<button class='btn-small btn-green'>Copy</button>";
        }
        return template;
    }
};
```

html file

```
<div id="grid1" class="gridStyle" ui-grid="gridOptions" external-scopes="states" ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-cellnav ui-grid-selection ui-grid-exporter></div>
```

Comment: You should probably show your code if you want people to offer suggestions.

Comment: I have edited my post and the problem here is it always display as text, all I want is just display the button. Please help @KreepN

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you ve found the asnwer or not but there are others who visit to find an answer.

```
 .Columns(c =>
   {
    c.Add().DataField("give a name").CellTemplate("<input type=button>");
   }
```

you can add a checkbox or other functions into the type.