# Set cell value based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ng-grid

I have a column binded to a `field` called `state`, which has the values: `S` or `L`. I want to map this to following:

`S` => `Short`,
`L` => `Long`

This is how the binding is defined:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
      columnDefs: [
        {name: 'action', field: 'state', width: 110, enableFiltering: false}
]
    };
```

I am already using `cellclass` and `celltemplating`, but either one is used for class application or event binding respectively. How do I set cell value based on an `ng-if`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. first, which is the condition? Based on what you want to set S or L in cells?

Comment: I found my answer on [@nabinca post here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26867340/830037)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps anyone, I ended up doing this:

```
let stateTemplate = "<div>{{row.entity.state == 'L' ? 'Buy' : 'Sell'}}</div>"

$scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
      columnDefs: [
        {name: 'action', field: 'state', cellTemplate: stateTemplate, enableFiltering: false}
],
data: someData
    };
```